# What is DSL in Scala?

Tags: scala, dsl

Going through various Scala related material, term DSL is used at many places.

Google search tells it is Domain specific language.

What exactly it means, and why is it that this term doesn't comes across while learning other languages like Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a DSL and where should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724/what-is-a-dsl-and-where-should-i-use-it)

Comment: There are plenty of DSLs in Java. We cannot tell you why you didn't come across them while learning Java. SQL is a DSL for querying relational data that is often used together with Java. HTML is a DSL for describing the semantic structure of hypermedia documents that is often used together with Java in webapps. Ant is a DSL for task-oriented programming in build systems, often used to build Java programs. JUnit is a DSL for writing unit tests in Java. Drools, Gradle, Apache Camel, and so on and so forth.

Comment: Taking JUnit as example, I so far thought of it as a testing framework. Is a framework an example of DSL?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the first part of the question ("what is a DSL?") is essentially answered by [What is a DSL and where should I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41724/what-is-a-dsl-and-where-should-i-use-it)

I'll try to answer instead to the second part: why are DSLs so popular in Scala?

The reason is that Scala (as opposed to other languages like Java) offers many syntactic facilities to provide DSLs.

For example, Scala has infix method applications:

```
someObject.someMethod(someArgument)

// can be written as

someObject someMethod someArgument
```

This makes introducing custom "operators" very easy in the language. A notable example is the [akka](https://akka.io/) DSL for sending messages to an actor:

```
actor ! message
```

which is a DSL mimicking the syntax of Erlang.

Another example of a syntactic facility in Scala is the "trailing block argument" (not sure it has a precise name):

```
def someMethod(x: Int)(y: String) = ???

// can be invoked as
someMethod(42)("foo")

// but also as
someMethod(42) { "foo" }
```

which is very interesting when the last parameter is a function:

```
def someOtherMethod[A, B](x: A)(f: A => B): B = ???

someOtherMethod(42) { a =>
  // ...a very long body
}
```

In other languages, blocks (`{ ... }`) are usually reserved to built-in control-flow structures (such as `if`, `while`, `for`, etc), but in Scala you can use this syntactic facility to build custom methods that resemble built-in control structures.

Those two features alone are distinctive enough for explaining why DSL are so pervasive in the Scala community.

Digging a bit deeper, we can also mention implicit conversions, which allow to add custom methods to any existing type. For example

```
implicit class TimesOps(x: Int) {
  def times(y: Int): Int = x * y
}

// then use as

2 times 4 // 8
```

This example combines the use of infix method application and implicit conversions.

Comment: Isn't that syntactic sugar, if not what makes dsl different from syntactic sugar @Gabriele Petronella

Comment: These look good, But I feel like lot of time it just adds to the learning curve of scala and which is preventing it to become a mainstream language, like java and python