# How to define a Scala function to call it without parens and dot

Tags: scala

In Scala, it is possible to call a function without using parentheses. For example, `"1,2,3" split ","` is a valid statement, which behaves the exact same way as `"1,2,3".split(",")`.

How can I define a function that can be called this way? My experience with this (creating a class with a member function, and then try to call it without `.` and `( )`) didn't work out, it just raised a syntax error.

Comment: Show us the code that didn't work. What you've described _should_ work as long as the method takes a single parameter.

Comment: please go through this tutorial https://www.scala-exercises.org/std_lib/infix_prefix_and_postfix_operators

Comment: I'm editing, it looks like I didn't say exactly what happened ; sorry. Thanks for the link, too @RajkumarNatarajan

Comment: Okay I found my mistake: I tried to do this with the apply operator, something like `"1,2,3" split "," 2`, which would have worked with `"1,2,3" split "," apply 2`. Should I answer myself, close the question, or rewrite it to ask if it is possible to do `"1" 0` instead of `"1"(0)` ?

Comment: Please look into about Scala DSL - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49216312/what-is-dsl-in-scala

Comment: @RaKa Would it really be necessary to completely define an "easier Scala" DSL for this to be possible? I mean, it is possible to override some operators, why not `()`?

Answer (score 0):

Putting "." is optional while calling a function , () also can be removed at the time of call if you have only one parameter or no parameter. For more explanation see this post

[Rules for Parenthesis and dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-f)